# Geting Zero Division Error while executing opencv moment function

Tags: python, opencv

I am developing an python application which finds the contours and moments in a particular image. The snippet is as followed.

```
self.blob = cv2.imread('output-17-03-07-13-28.bmp')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.blob,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
count = str(len(contours))
```

the following block calculates the contour which works perfect

```
self.areaArray = []
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    r = (randint(0,255))
    g = (randint(0,255))
    b = (randint(0,255))
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    self.areaArray.append(area)
    #print i,self.areaArray[i]
    cnt = contours[i]
    cv2.drawContours(self.blob, [cnt], 0, (b, g, r), -1)
```

the below block calculates moments

```
moments = [cv2.moments(cnt) for cnt in contours]
centroids = [(int(M['m10'] / M['m00']), int(M['m01'] / M['m00'])) for M in moments]
for c in centroids:
    cv2.circle(self.blob, c, 5, (0, 0, 0))
    cv2.imshow('img', self.blob)
```

once i run the script I am getting the error

```
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: Can you add the full traceback, please?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Project\blobANALYSIS.py", line 218, in <module>
    ui.setupUi(BlobAn)
  File "E:\Project\blobANALYSIS.py", line 34, in setupUi
    centroids = [(int(M['m10'] / M['m00']), int(M['m01'] / M['m00'])) for M in moments]
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Comment: Please find the `edit` link under your question

Comment: Obviously, `M['m00']` is 0, so please debug your own code to see why